# Use gMock for a class instantiated in smart pointers

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm reading the [gMock guide](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html) and find most of the examples showing how to use mock tests on "value" objects which seems odd since a big part of mocking is taking advantage of polymorphism (so use pointers or references):

```cpp
// Canonical example.
TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
  MockTurtle turtle;                           
  EXPECT_CALL(turtle, PenDown()).Times(AtLeast(1));

  Painter painter(&turtle);                       

  EXPECT_TRUE(painter.DrawCircle(0, 0, 10));     
}
```

My use case starts from a design (already in place), where mocking should be natural to use. To summarize the design, I'll use an example similar to the above:

1. There's an interface for drawing

```cpp
struct DrawI {
  virtual void point(int x1, int y1);
  virtual void line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) = 0;
};
```

2. There's a class that can be "injected" with `DrawI` objects that know how to draw:

```cpp
struct DeviceIO {
  DeviceIO(std::shared_ptr<DrawI> drawer, OtherProperties props);

  draw(Type t, Info i) {
    // Uses the implementation of DrawI supplied by the user.
  }

  // More methods here like log, persist, commit to Db
  // All of them depend on action objects that follow 
  // an interface and users can supply their own or use the default behavior.
}
```

I hope this simplification doesn't miss the point which is: **the behavior of `DeviceIO` can be tweaked by providing tailored implementations of objects like `DrawI`**.

The test suite uses mocking by creating dedicated classes for the available interfaces:

```cpp
struct NoOpDraw : DrawI {
  virtual void point(int x, int y) override { /*implementation*/ }
  virtual void line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) override { /*implementation*/ }
}

TEST(Device, Operations) {
  std::shared_ptr<DrawI> painter = std::make_shared<NoOpDraw>();
  DeviceIo io(painter, /* other properties */)

  // Normal Google test assertions (no gmock use)
}
```

The thing I find annoying is that gMock is not used/leveraged. But when trying to use it I find it impossible: I can define `NoOpDraw` as per the [gMock requirements](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html#how-to-define-it) but when trying to use it I can only pass values to the `EXPECT_CALL` macros:

```cpp
  std::shared_ptr<DrawI> painter = std::make_shared<NoOpDraw>();
  DeviceIo io(painter, /* other properties */);

  EXPECT_CALL(*painter, point).Times(1);

  // Using the io object in assertions will end up calling the mock 
  // methods, but not for the object I passed to the `DeviceIO` constructor.
  EXPECT_NO_THROW(io.draw(Point, /* info */);
```

Is there a solution? How can I use gMock to test objects conforming to an interface when the objects themselves are used polymorphically as part of a different class?

Comment: Please try to provide [mcve]. You haven't shown us the mock you wrote, the `EXPECT_CALL` won't compile, and quoting example from doc doesn't really add to your question. Also, how do you know that you call methods on different mock object than you set expectations on? Based on the incomplete example, everything looks correct. You pass a reference to `EXPECT_CALL` and `shared_ptr` to `DeviceIo`. All as it would be expected.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Isn't the `EXPECT_CALL` supposed to create (and maintain) a copy of the object it has been given? That is what I understand from the docs and it's where I attribute the wrong behavior. I'll try to improve the example, but essentially I cannot disclose the actual code - also it's huge, so if this minimal thing things looks correct I'll have to rethink what might be wrong. Will try to create a small implementation with the aforementioned design, I think compiler explorer has gtest/gmock

Comment: No, mocks are non-copyable. `EXPECT_CALL` in principle takes a mutable reference to mock object and sets expectations on it. It's on you to ensure the lifetime of mock - it will verify the expectations when it's destroyed. If the documentation isn't very clear on that, try writing a bug ticket on gtest repository, maybe they can clarify it more.

Comment: If `EXPECT_CALL` will take object by copy, it would mean that you can't test objects that have copy constructor deleted, check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/a4s51KKhf)

Comment: @zori You don't even have to delete copy constructor explicitly, it is implicitly deleted (because mock class members are not copyable): https://godbolt.org/z/sGrjMsn3x

Comment: Yes, that's true just to show